# Laravel авторизация при помощи стороннего api

Tags: php, json, laravel, oauth

Не давно поступила задача реализовать авторизацию в laravel через стороннее приложение. Есть api по которому можно получить token пользователя при правильно введенном логине и пароле.
Обращение к апи(post):

```
{
  "login": "login",
  "password": "123"
}
```

Ответ приходит в следующем формате:

```
{
  "user_id":"1",
  "token":"token"
}
```

Читал про Laravel Passport, но данный вариант не подходит, так как использует "свою" базу с пользователями. Прошу подсказать в какую сторону искать решение данной задачи.

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу -- то вам нужен собственный кастомный UserProvider унаследованный от EloquentUserProvider

Comment: @AK да, но Provider в laravel еще не знаком.